Data tables over an interactive map?
I have the longitude/latitude points of various communities within a Country. I'm interested in having a user be able to hover over a point on the map and be able to read the available data tables on it, which I currently have stored in pandas dataframes / excel files. I would also like to make it compatible with web applications if possible.
What software/packages would you recommend to tackle this problem? I believe I've seen something similar done in Power BI before, though I am not that experienced in it.

Dash by Plotly: if you prefer Python and want to leverage your pandas DataFrames directly
Folium or Bokeh: can be integrated into Flask or Django applications for web deployment
Leaflet.js: if you prefer JavaScript for creating interactive maps and visualisations, integrating Leaflet.js (or even D3.js) with your backend (possibly using Flask or Django as APIs) is a robust approach
